# numpy measure time - syntax error

Tags: python, numpy, time

I want to measure the time through numpy but I am not sure if I have the right arguments.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def svdsolve(a,b):
    u,s,v = np.linalg.svd(a)
    c = np.dot(u.T,b)
    w = np.linalg.solve(np.diag(s),c)
    x = np.dot(v.T,w)
    return x


A_=np.fromfile('dataA.bin',count=-1,dtype=np.float32)
B_=np.fromfile('dataB.bin',count=-1,dtype=np.float32)


s='svdsolve({0},{1})'.format(A,B)

mytime= timeit.Timer(stmt=s,setup='import numpy').timeit(100)

print mytime
```

Right now it gives me :

> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/timeit.py", line 136, in **init**
>       code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")   File "", line 6
>       svdsolve([[  1.86248358e+09   1.54404045e+09]
>                                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Also , I didn' understand (neither have I found a reference) on what arguments to pass at timer.
And I am not sure how to use the repetition `timeit(100)`

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but you should do `setup='import numpy as np'`, since you are referring to it as `np` in the method you are timing. Also, try `.format(repr(A), repr(B))`.

Comment: @tobias_k:Hello,using  import as np has no effect(altough as you mentioned I must use it) and using repr results in :NameError: global name 'svdsolve' is not defined

Comment: Try `from numpy import *` at the top (to have the `array` name needed to reconstruct the imputs) and `from __main__ import *` for `setup`.

Comment: @tobias_k:It gives SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level

Comment: Strange, this worked for me. Anyway, below answer is much better.

Comment: @tobias_k:Ok,thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `str` nor `repr` of a NumPy array is guaranteed to produce an output that can be used to reconstruct the original array. (`format` uses `str`, but `repr` wouldn't help.) Instead, `import` the arrays into the timed code's namespace. Assuming this code is being run as a script, that would be

```
mytime = timeit.Timer(stmt='svdsolve(A, B)',
                      setup='from __main__ import A, B, svdsolve'
                      ).timeit(100)
```

Comment: @tobias_k: Whoops, missed that one. Fixed.

Comment: @user2357112:Ok , this works!Can you tell me,the time is measured in seconds?And the timeit(100) ,the 100 repetitions ,what is this means?Should I use 100 always?Thnaks!

Comment: Just noticed that you do `import numpy` instead of `import numpy as np`, but it works anyway. Turns out you do not need the `import numpy` at all, as `svdsolve` already "knows" `np`.

Comment: @George: The time is in seconds. `timeit(100)` means that you're running `svdsolve(A, B)` 100 times and taking the total time. There's no good one-size-fits-all default value; it's a balance between running enough times to even out run-to-run runtime differences and not taking forever. The longer the timed code takes to run, the smaller the repetition number should be.